# How to remove shadow from image captured using mobile camera using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, contour, shadow, shadow-removal

I need to find largest rectangle in a image, but when I find contours shadow becomes part of the contour.

Any suggestions how to remove/minimize shadow.

Original image

[image]

Image with contours

[image]

Comment: Do you have a background model? If so, there's an old but effective Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence [paper](http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~iluetkeb/2006/surveillance/paper/activity/pami_sakbot.pdf) that show in Equation 8 a simple equation to threshold HSV values to remove shadows. Take a look, if you're interested I'll post the code as an answer.

Comment: background is not fixed it will be different for different images

Comment: Then that's not the way to go. Another [approach](http://nichol.as/papers/Gevers/Color-based%20object%20recognition.pdf) is to define a color space invariant to illumination changes. You can then work on this model where the shadows "magically" disappear. Have a look at Figure 1 in the paper. Another simpler (maybe simplistic) solution is to work better with your preprocessing. I suppose you need to extract only the barcode. That shouldn't be that difficult. If you post your code we'll give it a try.

Comment: I have to find image of interest (image region inside border) from the scene image (captured using camera) before extracting/analyzing any information

Comment: and the border is delimited by the two horizontal lines?

Comment: @Miki yes border will be delimited by two horizontal lines. But going forward form layout can be configured by the user

Comment: @nils share option for these images is "Shared to public on the web: no sign in required", they should be accessible.

Comment: Use **AdaptiveThreshold** rather than normal **Otsu Thresholding**, I was able to resolve same issue with OpenCV Java for Android

Answer (score 1):

You can use an edge dectector like Canny:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( "C:/Users/John/Documents/StackOverflow/t8keM.png" );
cv::Mat gray_image, dst, color_dst;

cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
Canny( gray_image, dst, 50, 200, 3 );
cvtColor( dst, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );

cv::imshow( "image", image );
cv::imshow( "canny", color_dst );

cv::waitKey();
```

With result:
[image]

After that you can have a go with cv::findContours() to find the rectangles.